# Emulate 'then' Promise behaviour with RxJS

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

With Promises I can chain the functions like the followings:

```
var p = promiseFactory('1');

p.then(function(data){
    /*Do something*/
    return promiseFactory('2');
}).then(function(data){
    /*Do something else*/
    return value;
}).catch(function(err){
    /*Here I can catch all exceptions threw in then methods*/
});
```

Can I render this behaviour with RxJS and Observable?If yes, how?

Comment: You can use `.flatMap`. Actually it depends on issue which you want to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.flatMap`., however in most cases it depends on issue which do you want to solve., for example consider HTTP calls chain, with `flatMap` you can solve it like this

```js
const $http = (url) => {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(url));
}

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const stream = $http(`${ url }/posts/1`)
  .flatMap(post => $http(`${ url }/comments?postId=${ post.data.id }`))
  .map((comments) => comments.data)
  .concatAll((comment) => comment)
  .map((comment) => comment.name)
  
stream.subscribe((res) => { 
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.14.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note, of course, that this is substantially more powerful than `Promise.then`.  `Promise.then` takes a single value and maps it through a function to return a new `Promise` that produces a single value.  `Observable.flatMap` takes a stream of 0 or more (potentially unlimited) values and expands each one out into 0 or more (potentially unlimited) values.  This is massively useful, but there is a necessary degree of additional complexity caused by it (eg data in a Promise can easily be handled in a single function but must be folded, scanned or otherwise reduced into a usable form first in Rx).